# How to setup PHP CodeSniffer that extend WordPress coding standards + autofix errors in VSCode?

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, phpcodesniffer

How to setup PHP CodeSniffer for project with personal rules that extend WordPress coding standards + autofix errors in VSCode on save?

I have [installed CodeSniffer globally](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer)

```
composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"
```

[WordPress coding standards are installed](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards) inside theme folder (so inside project they are at `/wp-content/themes/bideja/wpcs`)

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards.git wpcs
```

Inside theme folder I have created `phpcs.xml` which should inherit WordPress standards so I can customize it further

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Bideja">
    <description>Sniffs</description>

    <config name="installed_paths" value="wpcs" />

    <arg value="s"/>

    <exclude-pattern>assets/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>node_modules/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>vendor/*</exclude-pattern>

    <rule ref="WordPress-VIP">
        <exclude name="Generic.Files.EndFileNewline.NotFound" />
        <exclude name="WordPress.PHP.YodaConditions.NotYoda" />
    </rule>

</ruleset>
```

In Bash terminal inside theme, I can scan pages for errors and fix them

```
phpcs page.php
phpbcf page.php
```

But how can VSCode fix them on save? I get popup error:

```
phpcs: Referenced sniff "WordPress-VIP" does not exist
```

What should I place in User settings.json?

```
"phpcs.enable": true,
"phpcs.standard": "WordPress", // ?
```

I have tried setting

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths wpcs
```

When I check installed standards with `phpcs -i` I can see that WordPress standards are listed

```
 The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz, Zend, WordPress, WordPress-Core, WordPress-Docs, WordPress-Extra and WordPress-VIP
```

Also is CodeSniffer able to auto indent PHP and HTML or is that beyond of its capabilites? I am struggling with good indentation in VSCode

Answer (score 4):

I have git cloned WordPress coding standards into `C:/wamp64/www/tools/phpcs` and I have created custom `ruleset.xml` in `C:/wamp64/www/tools/phpcs/bideja`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Bideja">

    <arg value="s"/>

    <exclude-pattern>assets/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>node_modules/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>vendor/*</exclude-pattern>

    <rule ref="WordPress">
        <exclude name="WordPress.PHP.YodaConditions.NotYoda" />
        <!-- exclude other stuff as you wish -->
    </rule>

</ruleset>
```

Install new standards

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths C:/wamp64/www/tools/phpcs/wp-coding-standards/wpcs,C:/wamp64/www/tools/phpcs/bideja
```

Check if standards are installed

```
phpcs -i
```

Set default standard

```
phpcs --config-set default_standard bideja
```

Install `phpcbf` extension, add Environment variable for Path in Windows depending on your folder path

```
 C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

and modify `User settings.json` with correct path and name of your standard

```
"phpcbf.executablePath": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\phpcbf.bat",
"phpcbf.executablePathWindows": "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\phpcbf.bat",
"phpcs.standard": "bideja",
"phpcbf.standard": "bideja",
"phpcs.enable": true,
"phpcbf.onsave": true,
```

I hope I didn't forget something as I messed around this for hours but finally now after saving file VSCode fixes what it can.

Comment: another setup would be using `phpcs ./path/to/code --standard=./path/to/ruleset.xml` in a `composer.json` script, instead of changing settings